# WebControlAdapter cause telerik RadLoadingPanel to disappear

Tags: asp.net, telerik, controls, panel

I have a problem with `RadLoadingPanel`.
I made a class which inherits from `WebControlAdapter` and overrides `OnPreRender`.
I added to my project an App_Browsers/BrowserFile.browser where I do specify this :

```
    <adapter
        controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel"
        adapterType="ProjectClasses.MyWebControl, ProjectClasses" />
```

However, "binding" my adapter to the `WebControls.Panel` causes the `RadAjaxLoadingPanel` to never be visible.

If I remove this binding, it works perfectly. I really have no idea how I can solve this.

Any tip?

Thanks!